# C++ initialization of class members by nested constructors

Tags: c++, initialization

Is it possible to initializate a class like this?

```
Quaternion::Quaternion(){ //default without arguments
    Quaternion(0.,V3(0.,0.,0.));
}


Quaternion::Quaternion(double s, V3 v){ //with scalar and vector as a argument
    coords[0] = s;
    coords[1] = v[0];
    coords[2] = v[1];
    coords[3] = v[2];
}
```

because this is the output:

```
QUATERNION TEST
(2.122e-313:-3.22469e-232:2.122e-313:-1.998) //instanciated with Quaternion q;
(4:1:2:3) // instanciated with the Quaternion q(4,1,2,3);
(4:-1:-2:-3) // conjugated of the one above
```

and first one is not initializated as 0. as it should be... why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not in C++03, but the recent version of C++ allows *delegating* constructors:

```
Quaternion() : Quaternion(0.0, V3(0.0,0.0,0.0)) { }
```

In a delegating constructor, the initializer list must have precisely one element, which is another constructor (and obviously there mustn't be any circular references).

Pre-C++11 you don't really get around copy/pasting if you want to actually *initialize* your class members directly in the constructor. Maybe you would like to use default arguments, though? Some people object to those....

```
explicit Quaternion(double s = 0.0, V3 v = V3(0.0,0.0,0.0)) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Quaternion(0.,V3(0.,0.,0.));
```

This does not call the other constructor; instead, it creates a local temporary, which is discarded when the constructor returns.

In C++03, your only options are to initialise all the members in both constructors, or move the initialisation into a separate function which both constructors call.

In C++11, you can delegate to a different constructor, using slightly different syntax:

```
Quaternion::Quaternion() :
    Quaternion(0.,V3(0.,0.,0.))
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a feature called *delegating constructors* and was actually introduced in C++11, it was not available before. Note that the actual syntax looks different:

```
Quaternion::Quaternion() //default without arguments
  : Quaternion(0.,V3(0.,0.,0.)) // delegating constructor
{
}


Quaternion::Quaternion(double s, V3 v) //with scalar and vector as a argument
  : coords{ s, v[0], v[1], v[2] } // better version if you're using C++11 anyways
{
}
```

What your code did was that it created a temporary `Quaternion` object that was immediatly destructed.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a temporary instance in `Quaternion::Quaternion()`. If you don't want to make each constructor, define an initialization member function such as `init()` or wait till delegating constructor in C++11 is implemented in your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor just calls the constructor  with two arguments. Then puts the resulting Object to the stack and deconstructs it when it leaves the constructor.

So the Quaternion with 0 initilisation only lifes during construction time of a Quaternion with no arguments, but it is not the Quaternion, which is constructed by the default constructor.

What you can do is, to asssign standard values for parameters:

```
#include <cstdio>

class TestCl {
public:
  TestCl(int i = 0) {
    printf("%d\n", i); 
  };
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  TestCl f(1);
  TestCl s;
  return 0;
}
```